# pdfbox getAcroForm return null, while page - annots have field value

Tags: pdfbox

In particular pdf file, while trying to fetch getAcroForm, it gives null.

With the pdfbox jar debug options

- pages have annots and proper values inside the kid(0)
- at Root, field are missing, so getAcroForm gives null

Is there any way to fetch field / annots value bind with page, and not bind with root document.

[image]

Comment: Does the "repair acroform" item in the view menu work? If yes, try `document.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm(new AcroFormDefaultFixup(document))` on a copy of the document

Comment: Both pdDocument.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm() and document.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm(new AcroFormDefaultFixup(document)) returns null

Comment: pdDocument.getPage(0).getAnnotations() gives list of annotation, but unable to fetch value based on field name. it have get(index) and contains method only.

Comment: How about iterating over the widgets of the page and retrieving their `/V` (value) entry? (If the widgets don't have a `/V` entry, got to their parent - `/Parent` entry - and look there.)

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Can you please share details where I can fine "repair acroform" item in menu? On an PDF editor software?

Comment: in PDFDebugger, View menu, bottom.

Comment: okay, Tried "view" -> "repair acroform" and then "File" -> "sava as..". On saved copy getAcroForm() return null. Document was generated by adding inputs into the Adobe Sign environment directly.

Comment: Sadly that's not surprising if the code didn't work, because PDFDebugger does the same. If you can, please share the file. I suspect this was a file which was split from a bigger one and acroform wasn't kept (which is also what PDFBox does).

Comment: Yes correct, files splitted through pdfbox have same issue. Unable to extract fields value in the split pdf document.

Comment: In such cases, only way is to iterate pdDocument.getPage(0).getAnnotations()? or Is there any better options?

Comment: That repair acroform should have worked and I don't know why it didn't. It doesn't really make sense to me to split a form.